# Microservices - Databases table relations

Tags: database, microservices

When developing an application under the microservices arquitecture and using a database per service, how usually it's defined the owner of relationships?
For example, imagine an online shop system: you have a user service and a order service. The order service has at least a table for orders.

How do we know which user made a order? In a monolith we just use a database and we could just create a table with order_id and user_id but how usually is this done with microservices according to the best practices?
Should I just add a column to order table with a user_id from user table that belongs to user service database?

Thanks, I'm sorry if my explanation was too confusing.